# Angular component how to nest unordered list <ul> inside paragraph <p>?

Tags: angular, templates, html-lists, paragraphs

Angular throws an error when the following markup is present in an angular component's template.

```
Template parse errors: Unexpected closing tag "p"
```

---

```
<p>
  paragraph begins.
  <ul>
    <li>list item 1</li>
    <li>list item 2</li>
  </ul>
</p>
```

how to achieve this kind of nesting.?

Answer (score 1):

- A paragraph cannot contain a list.
- A list cannot contain a paragraph unless that paragraph is contained 
  entirely within a single list item.

Because `p` and `ul` are element rendered as block.